# Gitlab: how to view all issues resolved in a commit

Tags: gitlab

**Short version:** In gitlab how do I view all issues resolved in a commit (or merge request) given that I close issues using git comments (e.g. 'fix #10')?

**Long version:** In case there is an alternative solution what I'm ultimately trying to accomplish is this. Let's say developer fixes 10 issues, commits, creates merge request and deploys to the staging server. Now QA team needs to know the list of issues that were released so that they can test them. I know this can be done by manually labeling each issue(or assigning a milestone). But since gitlab already knows what issues were resolved in a commit it should be easy to view all issues associated with a commit/merge request. Is it possible to view them?